# Is there a way to embed a Google Docs form in a page without using plugins?

Tags: plugins, forms, contact, google, google-docs

I'm currently running a Wordpress blog. It's part of a school blog, so unfortunately, I don't have the permissions to install any plugins. I've got a "contact form" set up as a Google Docs form. Right now, I have a page linking to the form. Is there any way that I can embed it directly in the page without having to install a plugin?

Comment: Are you okay with a simple iframe? https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/how-tos/embed-docs

Comment: I tried, but no luck, it wouldn't show up. Is there a way to embed iframes without plugins?

Comment: Why would you need a plugin for a simple iframe?

Comment: I have no idea, but when I try putting the iframe into the html, wordpress erases it. How do you insert an iframe in wordpress? Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Only **administrators** can embed iframes etc. directly (for security reasons), but anyone can use the new [oEmbed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) feature providing it's a URL for one of around 30 websites. (That page explains how to add other sites to the list, but of course you need admin access to do so.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You can find a list of providers for embeddable coontent in `wp-includes/class-oembed.php`:

```
'#https?://(www\.)?youtube.com/watch.*#i'            
'http://youtu.be/*'                                  
'http://blip.tv/*'                                   
'#https?://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/.*#i'                  
'#https?://(www\.)?dailymotion\.com/.*#i'            
'#https?://(www\.)?flickr\.com/.*#i'                 
'#https?://(.+\.)?smugmug\.com/.*#i'                 
'#https?://(www\.)?hulu\.com/watch/.*#i'             
'#https?://(www\.)?viddler\.com/.*#i'                
'http://qik.com/*'                                   
'http://revision3.com/*'                             
'http://i*.photobucket.com/albums/*'                 
'http://gi*.photobucket.com/groups/*'                
'#https?://(www\.)?scribd\.com/.*#i'                 
'http://wordpress.tv/*'                              
'#https?://(.+\.)?polldaddy\.com/.*#i'               
'#https?://(www\.)?funnyordie\.com/videos/.*#i'      
'#https?://(www\.)?twitter.com/.+?/status(es)?/.*#i' 
'#https?://(www\.)?soundcloud\.com/.*#i'             
'#https?://(www\.)?slideshare.net/*#'                
'#http://instagr(\.am|am\.com)/p/.*#i'
```

Google is not in that list, so you have to ask the administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to paste the HTML of the Google Docs iframe directly into the page by using the TEXT mode of the edit form (instead of the VISUAL) mode.  That mode allows you to enter the HTML directly, while the WYSIWYG editor will either ignore it or treat it as text.